# Looking for the simplest way to extract tow strings from another in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have the following strings:

```
string a = "1. testdata";
string b = "12. testdata xxx";
```

What I would like is to be able to extract the number into one string and the characters following the number into another. I tried using .IndexOf(".") and then remove, trim and
substrings. If possible I would like to find something simpler as I have this to do in a
lot of parts of my code.

Comment: *"as I have this to do in a lot of parts of my code"* - Why not wrap it in a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proposed solutions so far are not correct.
First, after Split('.') or Split(".") you will have space in the beginning of second substring. 
Second, if you have more than one dot - you'll have to do something yet after the split.

More robust solution is below:

```
string a = "11. Test string. With dots.";
var res = a.Split(new[] {". "}, 2, StringSplitOptions.None);
string number = res[0];
string val = res[1];
```

Argument 2 specifies maximum number of strings to return. Thus when you have several dots - it will make a split only at the first.

Comment: the splitting string should be assignable to Char -> so should be "." instead of ". " - isn't it?

Comment: Not really. There's overload that takes string[] as first param. That's the point why this version won't have leading space at in the val. You could try to run it yourself - it is really works :)

Answer (score 4):

if the format is always the same you could do:

```
a.Split('.');
```

Comment: Note that it is not correct solution. See my comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339826/looking-for-the-simplest-way-to-extract-tow-strings-from-another-in-c/6339924#6339924

Comment: Please also note that I specified: "if the format is always the same.." -> although you certainly got point!

Answer (score 0):

```
string[]list = a.Split(".");
string numbers = list[0];
string chars = list[1];
```